# What's a simple way of sending game data between phones?

Tags: xna, networking, windows-phone-7

Using windows phones I need to send small amounts of data between phones in a turn based game. It's only a few bytes of data and does not need to be real time, something like in wordfeud or similar. There could be 2-4 players in one game and one players actions need to be sent to the other ones.

What would be the simplest way to manage this?

If it would be possible to easily extend to other platforms with monogame that would be nice but not a requirement right now (guess I'll cross that bridge when I come to it).

My initial hope was that this would be possible using some online service like scoreloop or openXlive that could handle all the online stuff (leaderboards, communications, social etc) but I haven't found one that can do it all.

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to create server for your game through which all players can interchange data, but that would require all players being online. Relatively easier in my opinion than making some wireless connection between different mobile devices and managing that.

Comment: UDP or NFC would be the best for a situation where you want to play with a group within the same WiFi zone but if you want to allow people to connect from different locations then you will have to set up a cloud service to at least handle the transaction of connecting players, retrieving the list of players looking for a game, and organizing the results. There are a few free-to-try cloud service providers(Appharbor, Windows Azure and others).

Comment: Uh, [sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket)?

Comment: @RobCurr yeah I'll want people to be able to play from different locations. Will check out appharbour and azure.

Comment: @Anko your comment doesn't really help. Anyone can post a wiki link to some related term, but without any advice on how to use it, it is rarely useful.

Comment: @user That's why I made a comment, not an answer. What I was trying to say is: What's wrong with just sockets? Would the requested abstraction be significant or generalisable enough to bother?

Comment: try this may be this will helpful for you. [Appwarp](https://github.com/shephertz/AppWarpDeveloper/wiki/Turn-based-gaming)

Comment: Looks really nice at a glance, I released my game with only high scores to compete with though :) this looks promising though, might be worth implementing.